# For deep namespaces in ruby, how best to manage coding style and scope operator annoyances?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, namespaces, scope

I find myself fighting deep namespaces (>= depth of 4), even when they logically make sense so to avoid some annoyances they cause.

To start, I like my code to fit nicely in the text editor window without it having to be overly wide. Though ruby conventional indent of 2 sp definitely helps, that pushes me to use the scope operator to avoid all the nested indents. But on the otherhand, using the scope operator brings its own set of problems...

First, to use constants somewhere upstream in the current namespace context, you have to use the full namespace of that constant for Ruby to find it. And since when I use the scope operator, the namespace depth is deep, it gets very long to reference constants and classes.

```
require 'a/b'
class A::B::C
  FOO = 'hi'
end
class A::B::C::D
  # FOO # can't do this. raises NameError: uninitialized constant; would work fine if classes used nested format, but then the extra indent makes for wide code.
  A::B::C::FOO # must use full reference when using scopes, ugh. Depending on the real names of A,B,C, this could be rather long as well.
end
```

Second, I run into a situation where I have to require files after my class definitions, which I prefer not to do (I like my require statements at the top), like so.

```
# File: a/b/c.rb
require 'a/b'
# require 'a/b/c/d' # can't put it here, otherwise you get uninitialize const A::B::C when a/b/c/d.rb is getting interpreted.
class A::B::C
  def initialize
    @d = A::B::C::D.new 
  end
end
require 'a/b/c/d' # it bothers me putting requires anywhere but at the top

# File: a/b/c/d.rb
require 'a/b/c'
class A::B::C::D
end
```

Something has got to give. Maybe I just need to give in and widen my editor and stick with nesting or maybe I'm not understanding how best to work in the context of a namespace using the scope operator.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I should handle deep namespaces which manages these problems? 
 1. keep code width down by minimizing indents
 2. be able to reference constants with just the constant name (FOO) when the constant is defined upstream of the current context
 3. keep all the require statements at the top of source code files

Comment: wrt closing the question: what's the problem? no comment to help me improve it? do you find my desires for clean too extreme? or was i just not clear? not cool to  simply close.

Comment: After looking through source code of other well known projects, it seems most nest their modules/classes and therefore don't encounter problems 2 and 3. The large amount of indentation seems not to bother these authors. I will follow their style as I am leaning to problem 1 as the lesser of the evils. To the closers of this marvelous question... thanks for nothing Jack holes!

Comment: Surprised nobody suggested: create new short constants within your own modules that reference other long constants, thereby aliasing them. Also `private_constant` those aliases, while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question yourself in your question :-)

You trying to avoid problem of too long scopes in your code.

Simply look - if you reference a constant which is somewhere deeply in your scope hierarchy - what you can do technically:

**Using the Ruby power**

If you have a module A and constant B in it you can try to use include A and access the constant B without referencing the module namespace.

But this may be not what you are looking for - because in this case your will include the module, but it's already defined there.

**Looking to the roots**

Look if you have to reference the constant in namespace A::B::C::D may you have wrong design of you system? The goal of OOP usually to keep data & methods as closer as possible.

You have two choices:

1. Improve design of you system if you feel smells.
2. Use long references no matter how they apprear in your editor - just repeat simple mantra: "I have this long reference here because it should be there and look this way."

And the problem will gone.

You don't necessary have to use the package-based namespaces similar to Java. You can just pick a more convenient and easy namespaces.

Comment: namespacing and mixins are two different things. My understanding of namespacing says "this class/module/constant only makes sense in the parent scopes context". mixins add behavior to a class. Sometimes I do have 5 deep and it doesn't smell. For example, DBQuery::QueryExpression::ResultHandler::RelationGenerator::ConditionalOp. None of the classes make sense to use outside of its parents scope. The clue is that ResultHandler by itself does not describe the class. QueryExpressionResultHandler works but since a QueryExpression class already exists QueryExpression::ResultHandler works best.

Comment: I wonder why all these classes/modules are all in hierarchy. For me it's reasonable if there would be one module - say ORM, and classes in it DBQuery, QueryExpession, etc. - then you can access them like ORM::DBQuery, ORM::ResultHandler instead, isn't it?

Comment: ORM::ResultHandler is not very descriptive since its a QueryExpression ResultHandler. This aside, depth like this is not uncommon. Rack has Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal; Turn has Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner; RubyGems has Gem::Package::TarWriter::BoundedStream.